# App's App Store Link

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, hyperlink, app-store

I have an app that logs the amount of miles you travel. I want to share the data by using different social networks, for example I have used the Facebook SDK and the user can post a status update. I want to advertise my app (of course) throughout that post, as well as present the data, but I want to direct the viewer of that post to the App on the store. So, even though I have not released the app yet, how can I find out/retrieve the apps link?

Comment: But I have seen other apps do that, they direct the user to buy the full app or review the app and they are not updated versions....

Comment: No, what I want to do is different, as I am coding right now, I want to put in the link of the app I am making, which has not released yet.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [iTunes Link Maker](http://itunes.apple.com/linkmaker/). It's a really good site: Gives you the link and the HTML of Apps/Musics/Movies/Books.

Answer (score 5):

If you have your own domain, what you can always do is make a page on your site redirect to the app page when you do finally submit it.  This is what I always do, and if I want to change it later to use the real one, I am free to do that.
For example:

```
www.yourwebsite.com/myapp --> http://someituneslink.com/myappslink
```