# "itms-apps://" URL for iOS app that has not been released yet

Tags: ios, app-store

My paid iOS app is under review to be released only in the Japan App Store.  I'd like to create the free version with a link to paid version, but don't have the URL of the paid version.

http://itunes.apple.com/linkmaker/ is mentioned in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10771730/apps-app-store-link), but when I search for my app there, it doesn't show up.

Another option suggested is to [create a permalink on our domain](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10792334/194309), but that will force the user through extra redirects.

iTunes connect gives my app url as starting with "http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/dumi-shuki-ying-yu/"  Clicking that link gives a warning that it's the app is currently only available in the US (though we released it only for Japan).

[image: The item you've requested is not currently available in the Japanese Store]

I have the SKU and bundle ID, but what can I use for the URL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The link you get in iTunes Connect should work just by replacing `http://` with `itms-apps://`.

That being said this alert is strange, do you have anything linked to your iTunes account set to U.S English? I'm guessing this is just automatic, and once your app is approved this link should work provided the user that clicks the link's iTunes account is associated with the Japanese store.

Answer (score 2):

This works on my end (Xcode 5 - iOS 7 - **Device**!):

```
itms-apps://itunes.apple.com/app/idYOUR_APP_ID
```

Code snippet (you can just copy& paste it):

```
#define YOUR_APP_STORE_ID 123456789 // Change this one to your app ID (get it from iTunes Connect)

static NSString *const iOS7AppStoreURLFormat = @"itms-apps://itunes.apple.com/app/id%@";

[NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:iOS7AppStoreURLFormat, YOUR_APP_STORE_ID]]; // Would contain the right link
```

Pay attention that we didn't use the app name (isn't needed and it is bad to use because it's subject to change). On iOs 7 you can also use "http" instead of "itms-apps" and that would have same result (won't open safari first like on older OS).

Last important thing is that **we haven't used the country data on the link** (usually "us" or any other) so the device would select the relevant one. If you do write "us" on the link (like the one you get from iTunes Link Maker) if you open that on Japanese device if could show an alert because store is probably set to Japan and won't open the link.